# Why is the build "details" deleted by default in TFS 2013 express?

Tags: express, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm in the process of configuring TFS 2013 express version for my team and in the retention policy of the build definition, when I select "Drop" as the "What to Delete", I get "Details, Drop".

When I go into "Build Delete Options" I see that the "Details" check box is checked by default and disabled. This means I cannot uncheck the check box.

1. Why is this set by default?
2. how do I uncheck it? or is there a work around?

Comment: If you are in the process of configuring TFS for your team, why are you using an old version? You should deploy TFS 2015.

Comment: You might be better using TFS Online! Http://tfs.visualstudio.com

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't uncheck the **Details** option. As you see on the **Build Delete Options** dialog:" details are always deleted by retention policies".

If you don't want to delete build details info, you can set the Retention Policy to be **Keep All**.